# Check if row exists with Azure Table Storage 1.8

Tags: .net, azure, azure-table-storage

The Azure Table Storage .NET client received a complete redesign with SDK 1.8. With the new SDK, how can I check if a row exists?

Here's an example from the [SDK's documentation](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/table-services/) of how to retrieve a single item:

```
TableResult retrievedResult = table.Execute(retrieveOperation);

// Print the phone number of the result.
if (retrievedResult.Result != null)
   Console.WriteLine(((CustomerEntity)retrievedResult.Result).PhoneNumber);
else
   Console.WriteLine("The phone number could not be retrieved.");
```

Based on the example, the retrievedResult.Result should be null, if no row was found. But actually **this isn't the case, as the table.Execute throws an exception if no row is found.**

This was true with the old SDK also: An exception was thrown if no row was found. But there was a property which turned this off:

```
TableServiceContext.IgnoreResourceNotFoundException = true
```

But where is this option hidden in the new SDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be in the same place in my SDK 1.8 as it has always been, but it has moved in the 2.0 version of the storage API. Is that what you're using?

[Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.TableServiceContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee758694.aspx) has moved to [Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.DataServices.TableServiceContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj733141.aspx).

The [property you're looking for](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/system.data.services.client.dataservicecontext.ignoreresourcenotfoundexception.aspx) seems to still be available there :)

Comment: I think I'm somewhat confused with the version numbers :) I'm using the Azure Storage SDK 2.0 which I think is part of the Azure SDK 1.8. Nervertheless, thank you for the help. I was able to find the property through "tableClient.GetTableServiceContext().IgnoreResourceNotFoundException"

Comment: One more comment: The storage client library distributed with the SDK is version 2.0.0.0 which has some bugs. I would recommend taking the latest version from Nuget. As of today, the latest version available on Nuget is 2.0.3.0.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using [TableEntity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.tableentity.aspx) concept, you can try the following code:

```
        CloudTable table = cloudTableClient.GetTableReference(tableName);
        TableOperation retrieveOperation = TableOperation.Retrieve<YourEntity>(partitionKey, rowKey);
        TableResult retrievedResult = table.Execute(retrieveOperation);
        YourEntity fetchedEntity = retrievedResult.Result as YourEntity;
```

If the entity does not exist, you will get fetchedEntity as null.

Comment: I think this is the same code as is shown in the documentation. The Execute-method throws an exception if the row isn't found. But it seems you can set "tableClient.GetTableServiceContext().IgnoreResourceNotFoundException = true" to get the null result instead on an exception.