# Check if a row exists in Azure Storage Table using the Azure.Data.Tables.TableClient

Tags: azure-table-storage

I'm using `Azure.Data.Tables.TableClient` (also looked at `Azure.Data.Tables.TableServiceClient`).

I want to check if a record exists in the Azure Table given a specific Partition Key and Row Key. Calling the `TableClient.GetEntity<T>` throws an exception if it gets 404 from the server rather than returning null.

I've searched on SO and there is one solution [available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14405811/check-if-row-exists-with-azure-table-storage-1-8) but it uses the older `CloudTable`.

I've tried looking at the `TableServiceClient` options but so far haven't had any success finding a good solution that doesnt require catching the exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably use [`Query`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.data.tables.tableclient.query?view=azure-dotnet#azure-data-tables-tableclient-query-1(system-string-system-nullable((system-int32))-system-collections-generic-ienumerable((system-string))-system-threading-cancellationtoken)) and specify your query as `PartitionKey eq 'partition-key-value' and RowKey eq 'row-key-value'`.

If the entity does not exist, you will receive an empty array back instead of error. If the entity exists, you will receive an array with just 1 entity.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the above answer, you also need to include the type you are trying to query to avoid this error.

[image: error without specifying type]

For your use case, you want to do something like `tableClient.Query<TableEntity>(x => x.RowKey == rowKey);`. You can do the same with partition key as well. Just make sure you change the variables around. Hope this helps!